# Can You Use MSVC 6.0's Debugger to 'Step Into' a Macro?

Tags: winapi, debugging, visual-c++

I am using MSVC 6.0 to call a macro in the Win32API and I'm getting an access violation.  I know that the pointers I'm passing to the macro contain valid addresses, though they're evidently not pointing to the correct data.

The macro accepts multiple pointers, and I'm not sure which pointer is erroneous, so I'd like to use MSVC's debugger to 'step into' the macro to see exactly where the problem is.  When I've tried thus far, the debugger just throws the access violation error.

Is it possible to 'step into' a macro using MSVC 6.0's debugger?  If not, is there anyway for me to check what the macro expands to, so I can get a better idea of what I'm not doing correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to trace the macro code, the only way would be to find the definition of the macro, manually "instantiate" the macro code (substituting the parameters) in place where it is "called", and then trace it in the debugger as ordinary code.

Alternative variant would be to step through the disassembly, if your skill level is sufficient to back-associate the disassembled code with the original macro code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot step into the macro because at the point compiler does its job, the macro is already expanded. However, you can step *through* a macro - if you just do "step", you will actually step through all code inside the macro as if it was expanded, line by line. If you to "step into", you will step into every function call made from that macro. If the macro is small enough, and/or you know it very well, you can do a "blind step through" that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can step into functions that are called from the macro but as far as I know can not really step through the macro lines themselves. And yes if you code compiles - you can find the macro definition (use MSVC function/class browser to find where it is defined, some header file probably)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just step into the disassembly - usually, even if you're not an assembly expert, short runs of code (a few lines) the assembly map back to the C/C++ code pretty readily (especially in non-Release builds). Hopefully the macro isn't so hairy that that isn't the case here.

Remember that plenty of debugging occurs even without source code, so having the source and the disassembly together usually isn't too bad. And if it's something you haven't much experience with, it's great experience to get.